# What alternative of `spread` function and tidyr package should I use?

Tags: r, tidyr, spread

I want to use `spread` function from tidyr package but my RStudio says
"Error in spread(., nama_event, created_at) :
could not find function `spread`"
Therefore, I want to install tidyr package but it doesn't exist in RStudio 1.4.1.

Comment: You are looking for pivot_wider?

Comment: Did you install the package, and did you load it before calling the function? This doesn't seem like a problem that's specific to `tidyr` or `spread`, just about generally loading things properly

Comment: Thanks Camille, you're right it didn't load properly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `spread` you should use `pivot_longer`.
https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html

To install a package, you shoud use `install.packages`.